# Logitech K700 (Revue) keyboard/trackpad combo - Function Key (F1-F12) emulation

Tags: keyboard, emulation, retropie

With the Logitech K700 (Logitech Revue) wireless keyboard/trackpad combo, is there any way to emulate the function keys (F1-F12)?  [EmulationStation](http://aloshi.com/emulationstation), which is the frontend for [RetroPie](http://blog.petrockblock.com/retropie/), uses function keys to exit games and perform some other important system functions.

I'll take as much info as I can get about making this keyboard/trackpad work better with the Pi.

Comment: Which keys do you want to remap? The numeric 1..0, `-` and `+` keys?

Comment: It looks like EmulationStation has a way to reconfigure the key bindings. I would ask them how.

Comment: You could always remap some keys in the debian, if Craig's solution is not working. e.g. http://www.linuxscrew.com/2008/09/15/faq-how-to-disableremap-a-keyboard-key-in-linux/ (I think this requires X, and I'm not sure RetroPie uses X)

Comment: Remapping the functions in specific apps is nice, but if there was also a way to emulate the actual key press using the built-in function key on the keyboard or some other combination, it would be really good to know.  Then I can just Ctrl-Alt-(F1 equivalent) like I usually do, as well as being able to use more default key settings for prebuilt images.  If not, I can learn to cope.

Answer (score 3):

to emulate function keys F1 - F12 on a standard US keyboard (equaling your Logitech K700 design) I suggest to do the following:

first create some file e.g. '/etc/X11/Xmodmap' with these contents:

```
keycode 66 = Mode_switch

keycode 10 = 1 exclam F1
keycode 11 = 2 at F2
keycode 12 = 3 numbersign F3
keycode 13 = 4 dollar F4
keycode 14 = 5 percent F5
keycode 15 = 6 asciicircum F6
keycode 16 = 7 ampersand F7
keycode 17 = 8 asterisk F8
keycode 18 = 9 parenleft F9
keycode 19 = 0 parenright F10
keycode 20 = minus underscore F11
keycode 21 = equal plus F12
```

second do a

```
xmodmap /etc/X11/Xmodmap
```

this will map a 'caps lock' key pressed together with some '1' - '=' key to F1 - F12.

Certainly you may define any other mode switch key than 'caps lock' for this. I personally like to use 'caps lock' for such purposes because I consider it absolutely useless if used in it's traditional way.

Comment: This solution assumes that X is running, correct?

Comment: correct. Nobody says a few words about this RetroPie thing. Is it based on X at all?

Comment: https://github.com/petrockblog/RetroPie-Setup/wiki/EmulationStation#when-i-start-a-game-i-lose-keyboard-input-and-have-to-power-off-to-reboot
I don't think RetroPie usually uses X, but I may be wrong about that. These directions are still very good.  Thank you.